# For Python Dask, what is the difference between persist and scatter?

Tags: python, dask

I have been reading the doc and searching online a bit, but I am still confused about the difference in between `persist` and `scatter`.

I have been working with data sets about half a TB large, and have been using `scatter` to generate futures and then send them to workers. This has been working fine. But recently I started scaling up, and now dealing with datasets a few TB large, and this method stops working. On the dashboard, I see workers not triggered and I am quite certain that this is a scheduler issue.

I saw this [video](https://blog.dask.org/2018/06/26/dask-scaling-limits) by Matt Rocklin. When he deals with a large dataset, I saw first thing he does is to `persist` it to the memory (distributed memory). I will give this a try with my large datasets, but meanwhile I am wondering what is the difference between `persist` and `scatter`? What specific situations are they best suited? Do I still need to scatter after I persist?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First with persist, imagine you have table A, which is used to make table B, and then you use B to generate two tables C and D. You have two chains of lineage with A->B->C and A->B->D. The A->B sequence can be computed twice, once to generate C and another one for D. This is because of the lazy evaluation nature of Dask.

Scatter is also called broadcast in other distributed frameworks. Basically, you have a sizeable object that you want to send to the workers ahead of time to minimize the transfer. Think like a machine learning model. You can scatter it ahead of time so it's available on all workers.

Comment: So if you already did persist, would you scatter again, or vice versa?

Comment: They are for different use cases. Persist is for the big DataFrame you don't want to recompute. That DataFrame can be spread across the workers, but the workers hold different parts of the DataFrame. Scatter is meant for a relatively smaller object to be sent only once to all of the workers. All workers hold a copy of the original object.